# Random single letter within BODY tag

Tags: wordpress

I have a random "d" letter between my opening and closing `BODY` tag right after the footer tag in my Wordpress installation which is causing it to display a random "d" letter site wide near my header/menu area.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `header.php` and `index.php` templates.

Answer (score 0):

Review if your Theme has properties to add content after/before the body. If so, try to found the property in your theme options and remove the letter.